# Several instances of a single file upload (using fine-uploader)

Tags: javascript, php, fine-uploader

I would like to use fine-uploader in my JQuery based front-end.

On my webpage the user has to upload a dozen of specific documents to the PHP back-end.

I'd like to have for each document a separate button (image link instead of a regular button), to choose exactly 1 file (.pdf, .doc, .xls). The selected file is then shown in a disabled input field and automatically uploaded. My jQuery callback then has the corresponding file UUID from the back-end.

Is it possible to hide/disable the green progressbar when/after uploading?

Where do I start? Do I need different instances for each of my files? Could someone direct me to a simmilar code sample?

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your questions in order:

- Have a look at the [`extraButtons` option/feature](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/extra-buttons.html).  This will allow you to point Fine Uploader at as many extra upload buttons you want.  Fine Uploader will attach a "hidden" `<input type="file">` to each.
- You can make any changes you want to the look and feel of Fine Uploader's default UI via your own CSS rules, or you can design your own UI entirely and just leverage Fine Uploader's API.  You can also get a handle on any specific file's parent element in the UI via the [`getItemByFileId` method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getItemByFileId).  This will return the parent `HTMLElement` that contains all elements in the UI for that specific file.